# A question of permutations and combinations with six cards and six envelopes.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Six cards and six envelopes are numbered *1,2,3,4,5,6* and cards are to be placed in envelopes so that each envelope contains exactly one card and no card is placed in the envelope bearing the same number.  Moreover, the card numbered *1* is always placed in envelope numbered *2*.  What is the number of ways it can be done?

Comment: So, we have the derrangements with $\sigma(1)=2$

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, I have not been introduced to derrangements so there has to be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let S be the set of all ways to distribute the cards, and

let $E_i$ be the set of distributions where card $i$ goes into envelope $i$ for $3\le i\le 6$.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, we get

$\displaystyle\big|\overline{E_3}\cap\cdots\cap \overline{E_6}\big|=\big|S\big|-\sum_i\big|E_i\big|+\sum_{i<j}\big|E_i\cap E_j\big|-\cdots$

$\hspace{1 in}\displaystyle=5!-\binom{4}{1}4!+\binom{4}{2}3!-\binom{4}{3}2!+\binom{4}{4}=\color{red}{53}$

Answer (score 2):

A *derangement* is a permutation of $n$ objects that leaves none of the items unchanged.

In **general**, card $i$ does not go in envelope $i$, which is equivalent to solving the problem with $n − 1$ cards going into $n − 1$ envelopes.  Then each of the remaining $n − 1$ cards has exactly 1 forbidden choice from among the remaining $n − 1$ envelopes.  Card $i$ takes the envelope $1$ and the problem reduces to $n − 2$ cards and $n − 2$ envelopes.

Thus the number of derangements of $n$ items is denoted $!n$ and obeys the recursion relation:

$!n = (n-1)(!(n-1) + !(n-2))$,

where $!n$ is read "$n$ subfactorial" and obeys

$!n = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n\frac {(-1)^i} {i!}$.

Noting that $!1 = 0$, $!2 = 1$, one works up to find the number of derangements of 6 items is $!6 = 265$.

Your current constraint that card 1 goes to envelope 2 (but not $3$, $4$, $5$ or $6$) means that we have just 1/5 of the total derangements available, so your answer is $265/5 = \color{red}{53}$.

Comment: +1 Yes, although the OP might have preferred more explanation of why the recurrence relation holds.